# Why is azure's CloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri returning an HTTPS: for the blobls url?

Tags: url, azure, blob

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");

// create container
Storage = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

Container = Storage.GetContainerReference("container");
Container.CreateIfNotExist();

// configure for public access
var permissions = Container.GetPermissions();
permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
Container.SetPermissions(permissions);

...

CloudBlockBlob blob = Storage.GetBlockBlobReference(blobname);
blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);
url = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

//url returns:  https://myazureacct.blob.core.windows.net/...
```

I can access the resource with http://myazureacct....  but why is AbsoluteUri returning https?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Uri is created by the library using the underlying connection string/client - and I'm guessing that your "DataConnectionString" contains "UseHttps=true" - hence why the url's the library is using (and producing) are HTTPs.

---

At a slightly deeper level than that, you can access the blob storage service using http or https - just as you can access table and queue storage too. If you're working within a single Azure data center, or if you are working with non-sensitive data, then you are free to use http - otherwise https is preferred for your security.

Comment: another option, which I use, is to add the following in the connectionstring: "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https"